# XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/main.7f4ca7158af3e942ff90.hot-update.js:330:14)

Tags: axios, entity

i am getting this error when i try to fetch api using axios passing it my entity framework api generated using swagger.here  am trying to get data from the api
Here's my code
const FetchAPI = () => {

```
const fetchAPI =() => {
    axios.get("https://localhost:7270/api/Product")
    .then((response)=>{
        console.log(response);
    })
    
}
```

return

i dont know whats wrong i am new to this concept, uisng axios for the first time it would be great if nyone  could help me out with it

Comment: `https://localhost:7270/api/Product`... I'm assuming it is `http`. Can you try with `http`?